# Unexpected character (j) at position 9

Tags: java, json

I followed this tutorial to read a json file i created previously

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-the-contents-of-a-json-file-using-java

I joined this with java swing and jFile Chooser.
Below this is the code:

```
fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Select a file to open");
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        // int returnValue = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);

        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(selectedFile.toString()));
                            JTree tree = (JTree) jsonObject.get("JTree");
                            Connection conn = (Connection) jsonObject.get("Connection");
                            new Principale(tree, conn). setVisible(false);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

        }
```

If I try to print the selectedFile.toString() it returns the correct path, but when I run the project I have this error when i get .parse():

> Unexpected character (j) at position 9.   at
>   org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)    at
>   org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)  at
>   org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)  at
>   org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)

This is instead the file .json i created with another class in java swing following this tutorial:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-write-create-a-json-file-using-java

```
{"JTree":javax.swing.JTree[,0,0,167x818,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@3271444,flags=16777576,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,editable=false,invokesStopCellEditing=false,largeModel=false,rootVisible=true,rowHeight=0,scrollsOnExpand=true,showsRootHandles=true,toggleClickCount=2,visibleRowCount=20],"Connection":oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@556a66b7}
```

If anyone could tell me how to solve, i will be very grateful.

**EDIT**

This is how I created json File with java swing ad jFileChooser

```
JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame();
        //Creating a JSONObject object
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("JTree", (JTree) tree);
        jsonObject.put("Connection", (Connection) conn);
        saveChooser = new JFileChooser();
        saveChooser.setDialogTitle("Specify a file to save");   

        int userSelection = saveChooser.showSaveDialog(parentFrame);

        if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File fileToSave = saveChooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());
            try{
                FileWriter myObj = new FileWriter(fileToSave.getAbsolutePath() + ".json");
                myObj.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
                myObj.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ie){
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is a wrong JSON you have in the end. Should be: `{"JTree":"javax.swing.JTree[,0,0,167x818,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@3271444,flags=16777576,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,editable=false,invokesStopCellEditing=false,largeModel=false,rootVisible=true,rowHeight=0,scrollsOnExpand=true,showsRootHandles=true,toggleClickCount=2,visibleRowCount=20]","Connection":"oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@556a66b7"}`

Comment: so, even if the field Connection isn't a string i have to put it into " "? Because the field Connection is of the type javax.sql.Connection and the field jTree is of the type  javax.swing.JTree

Comment: No, but in your case, it is a string

Comment: Sorry i didn't specify... the field Connection is of the type javax.sql.Connection and the field jTree is of the type javax.swing.JTree

Comment: these fields are java types and definitely not supported by json

Comment: Oh okay... i thought i could pass any type to json object

Comment: Erm ... nope.  There are lots of Java classes that are simply not serializable.  Not as JSON and not as anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the way your code is reading JSON.

The real problem is that the file you are trying to read does not contain valid JSON.  The JSON parser can't understand it.  (No Java parser will be able to understand it!).

The hypothetical solution would be one of the following:

- Fix the program that is generating the file to generate valid JSON.
- Write a custom parser to read the file.

However, it looks like the code that generates the file has called `toString` on a `javax.swing.JTree` object and on a JDBC `Connection` object in a vain attempt to serialize them.  Unfortunately, neither of those is classes serializable in any useful sense.  Even if you could parse the text in the file, you would not be able to reconstruct either the `JTree` or the `Connection`.

So you probably need to rethink what you are trying to do.  What are you actually trying to achieve with this code and the corresponding serialization code?  What are you actually trying save ... and why ... and is there another way to achieve what you are trying to do?

Comment: So, if I should want to reconstruct JTree and Connection in what file of which format should I save these information?

Comment: Told me json was one of the possible

Comment: You could conceivably extract the information in the `Jtree` and save that.  I don't think it makes any sense to save a JDBC connection ... and it is not possible.  Maybe you could save a JDBC URL + credentials so that you could create another connection.

Comment: *"Told me json was one of the possible"* ... Huh?